# click versus submit event handler precedence

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have the following form,

```
<form id="my_form" action="." method="post">
    ...
    <input id="update" type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

and the following jQuery event handlers,

```
$(document).on('click', '#update', function() {
    create_dialog("Title", "Dialog text", {
        modal: true,
        dialogClass: 'confirm_update',
        buttons:
        [
            {
                text: "Confirm",
                click: function() {
                    $('#my_form').submit();
                }
            },
        ]
    });
    return false;
});
```

The create_dialog(...) method just calls JQueryUI's .dialog() method with the appropriate params.

We've been having a bug that we are unable to reproduce, where a user will click the "Confirm" button in the jQuery dialog, but the form isn't getting submitted (if it helps, it only seems to happens in IE11, but we haven't been able to reproduce the behavior there either). I was just wondering what is the order the events are triggered when the form submit button is clicked. Is the click handler always evaluated before the button's default submit behavior, and might there be any exceptions to this in this context?

We are using jQuery 1.8.3 and jQueryUI 1.10.3 for the dialog.

**EDIT**: Corrected the type in the `<input>` element to "submit" instead of "hidden".

Comment: change this `$(document).on('click', '#update', function()` to `$('#update').on('click', function()` (since id must be unique)

Comment: You could just try... But click will be triggered before submit cause that's what happens first, without click, no submit...

Comment: @MehdiDehghani although you're probably right about not delegating the event, it's not uniqueness or not that drives delegation... If the button is somehow dynamically generated, your code won't work while OP's will.

Comment: true, I know that, if you add the button on run-time, you need that so

Comment: @LaurentS The "submit" button is not dynamically generated, but the "Confirm" button is.